# How to differentiate between /tʃ/ and /t/,/ʃ/ in some words' pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I checked the pronunciation of *posthumous* in dictionary which reads /ˈpɑːstʃəməs/, and then wondered if it is /t/ and /ʃ/ separately as in *tip* /tɪp/ and *shoe* /ʃuː/ or it reads /tʃ/ as in *chair* /tʃer/. I understand that the sounds are very similar so possibly it doesn't make any difference either way. Is that the same for native speakers, too? I mean is both versions of saying the word true and it doesn't matter? If not, is there a rule or a trick to help me read the pronunciation of the word and learn it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases where /tʃ/ is pronounced as two separate sounds, /t/ followed by /ʃ/. However, this consonant sequence is very rare, it can only occur when the consonants are separated into different syllables, and it only occurs in **compound words.**

When it's necessary to disambiguate, the sequence of two distinct sounds may be written as /t.ʃ/, and the single affricate sound of "chair" may be written as /t͡ʃ/. *Posthumous* is pronounced with the affricate phoneme /t͡ʃ/ (or, as Curtis White mentions, certain speakers may use /tj/).

Example words with /t.ʃ/: *hotshot, nutshell, batshit, potshot, sweatshirt, sweatshop.* Note that they are all compound words spelled with "t" followed by "sh". I got them from a [Onelook Dictionary Search of the sequence "tsh"](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*@tsh@*&scwo=1&sswo=1). There are no words where "t" or "th" represents /t.ʃ/.

Phonetically, /t͡ʃ/ and /t.ʃ/ differ on average in various ways. The ones I can think of are:

- the period of friction (the [ʃ] sound) is longer on average in /t.ʃ/ than in /t͡ʃ/.
- the /t/ in /t.ʃ/ may be subject to glottal replacement, resulting in [ʔʃ]

Answer (score 1):

It differs by dialect, but some dialects pronounce it as:

/tʆ/ like chair, so /ˈpɑːs**tʆ**əməs/

However, other dialects, including mine, pronounce it as /t/ and /(h)ju/, so /ˈpɑːs**t(h)j**əməs/

Others still may say: /p**ostˈhju**məs/

I would pick whichever one who feel most comfortable with and be consistent. You should be understood by most people whichever one you pick.

Comment: So /ʆ/ is not an option here any way. It's either /t(h)j/ or /tʆ/. Can I assume whenever I see /tʆ/ it would be /tʆ/ as in **ch**air and not /t/ and /ʆ/ separately?

Comment: I think that would be a fair assumption to make. I don't know of any English dialects that separate these phonemes, at least not within a word.